# Draw a line on ImageView set by Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-canvas, paint, picasso

I am trying to figure out how to simply draw a line on an image that is being set in Picasso. I found that if I simply set the image, given a URI, with Picasso and try to draw paint to it using the following:

```
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
image.draw(canvas);
topEdge = new Paint();
topEdge.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
topEdge.setStrokeWidth(5);
canvas.drawLine(c1.getX(), c1.getY(), c2.getX(), c2.getY(), topEdge);
```

Then I get a crash saying that the bitmap needs to be mutable first. So I added this above that code:

```
Bitmap workingBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

And then create the canvas with `new Canvas(mutableBitmap)` instead. This removed the crash, however nothing is being drawn. I believe this is because my Picasso is setting the image before, so now I need to reset Picasso with this new mutable bitmap. The problem is this code is in the onSuccess() callback for Picasso. What can I do to allow Paint to be drawn on an image through Picasso?

Answer (score 3):

just follow the steps below:

1. Write your own class extends the class Transformation like below:

   ```
    class DrawLineTransformation implements Transformation {

     @Override
     public String key() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return "drawline";
     }

     @Override
     public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       synchronized (DrawLineTransformation.class) {
         if(bitmap == null) {
           return null;
         }
         Bitmap resultBitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
         Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
         Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
         canvas.drawLine(0, resultBitmap.getHeight()/2, resultBitmap.getWidth(), resultBitmap.getHeight()/2, paint);
         bitmap.recycle();
         return resultBitmap;
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   2、Add the Transformation to RequestCreator created with Picasso.load() function like below:

   ```
   Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
   DrawLineTransformation myTransformation = new DrawLineTransformation();
   picasso.load("http://www.baidu.com/img/bdlogo.png").transform(myTransformation).into(imageview);
   ```

That's all steps you need to do , just enjoy!